# Flutter apps not running on android

Tags: gradle, flutter

Applications are not running on android but running well on ios, error says that there is a problem in gradle although native android projects run well in android studio, I tried google and other threads on stackoverflow with no luck.**

N.B: the error occurs regardless the project, it always happens even with newly created projects in flutter. Thanks

```
* Error running Gradle:

ProcessException: Process "/Users/apple/Documents/flutter_work/tqtqt/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Unable to start the daemon process.

This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.

For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.

Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Please read the following process output to find out more:

-----------------------

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Command: /Users/apple/Documents/flutter_work/tqtqt/android/gradlew app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `flutter clean` on project folder and run it again.